# Solution to call a system function or standalone application from Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

Is there any way to call a system function or standalone application from a Java Applet? (and tweak the SecurityManager) ?

The problem is that I have this standalone java application that I have to control through an applet.

Best regards,
Xander

Comment: What's wrong with Java Web Start?  That seems simpler and doesn't involve a security hole.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html

Answer (score 0):

If this tweak exists the whole java security does not exist and all Sun engineers that developed it should go home.

So, obviously you cannot run any non secured code from applet unless it is signed.

If applet is unsigned you can just communicate with server where this applet has been downloaded from. So, if you wish to make your stand alone application and applet to communicate you can either sign your applet or implement indirect communication via server.